# Excel VBA Pound and Colon Signs Meaning?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to understand a vba function with the pound and colon symbol interspersed throughout it.

VBA function:

```
kn = 1#: pn = 1#:  y = 1#
```

I know the pound sign is used to declare a variable as a double in Excel VBA. However, it does not seem to make any sense in terms of the above line. What does the above function do?

Comment: What doesn't make sense? The `#` is used to declare as double otherwise '1' would be interpreted as type integer. The `:` is used to allow variable declaration all on one line instead of separate lines. I agree it could be written `kn = pn = y = 1#`

Comment: Ahh ok didnt know that the colon could be used to chain declarations in one line as above...Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The colon (`:`) is a statement delimiter. It would be equivalent to a new line in VBA, or a semicolon in C (just to quote a random example). It allows you to write several instructions on a single line rather than going to a new line each time.

The pound (`#`) is a short-hand type specifier that forces your literals to be `double`, so basically `1#` is almost equivalent to `1.0`.

Answer (score 10):

****Here is a Cheat Sheet for DataTypes ****

Variable End with:

```
$ : String
% : Integer (Int32)
& : Long (Int64)
! : Single
# : Double
@ : Decimal
```

Start with:

```
&H : Hex
&O : Octal
```

Visual Studio .Net added Literal Types ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters))

Value End with: (For more complete list, refer the the reference)

```
S : Short (Int16)
I : Integer (Int32)
L : Long (Int64)
F : Single
R : Double
D : Decimal
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off Romain's response,
`kn = 1#: pn = 1#:  y = 1#`
is equivalent to:

```
kn = 1#
pn = 1#
y = 1#
```