# What is the meaning of two dot in this code?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to learn what is usage of two dot in excel vba.

```
Sub loadparts(a)    
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    Dim lists()    
    b = 2    
    'what is the meaning of two dots.

x:
    If Cells(b, a) <> "" Then   
        ReDim Preserve lists(1 To b - 1)   
        lists(b - 1) = Sheets(b, a)

        b = b - 1: GoTo x
    End If

    UserForm1.ListBox1.List = lists()  
End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/how-to-label-statements

Comment: It's marks `x` as a *label* that you can `goto`. The modern form of old BASIC line-numbers.

Comment: The two dots after the x mean that x is a label, you can use goto to jump to it. In your example this is done after 1 is subtracted from b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two dots are called a colon. And the colon has two functions in Visual Basic for Applications

**Defining a label:** In your example `x` is a label. You can use labels to jump to a specific part of your code, with the `goto` statement. In your example, this happens on this line:

```
b = b - 1: GoTo x
```

And you can use it to **separate instructions** (which incidentally happens on the same line). In VBA we usually separate statements with newlines, but one could also use the colon. Though this usually doesn't read too easily. Grabbing the same line of code again:

```
b = b - 1: GoTo x

is equivalent to

b = b - 1
GoTo x
```

Answer (score 2):

In this, the 'two dots', or the colon, is a delimiter of statements. It is a shorthand way of writing multiple lines of VBA code, in one line. For example...

`b = b - 1: GoTo x`

is equivalent to

```
b = b - 1

GoTo x
```

[Excel VBA Pound and Colon Signs Meaning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649101/excel-vba-pound-and-colon-signs-meaning)