# .PivotFields(1).Orientation = 1: .PivotFields(1).Position = 1 < what does it mean?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

This is the code to create a pivot table using VBA.
But there is something I don't understand.

> .PivotFields(1).Orientation = 1: .PivotFields(1).Position = 1

Specifically

1: .PivotFields(1)

I don't know what this means.

I've searched the internet, but I can't quite figure it out.
can you please explain?

```
Dim wkSht As Worksheet                         '
Dim rngAll As Range
Dim rngT As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set rngAll = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(3))

On Error Resume Next
    
Set wkSht = Sheets("PivotTable1")

If Err <> 0 Then
    Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(1)).Name = "PivotTable1"
    Err.Clear
Else
    MsgBox "The sheet already exists." & vbCr & vbCr _
    & "Delete and then try again", 64, "sheet creation error"
                                                     
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set rngT = Cells(1, 1)

                               
 ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    rngAll, Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    rngT, TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6

                                                          
                                                          
                                                          
                                                          
With Sheets("PivotTable1").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    .AddDataField .PivotFields(8), "SUM", xlSum
    .PivotFields(1).Orientation = 1: .PivotFields(1).Position = 1 #this part
    
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Orientation = is it a row/column/page/data/hidden field?  In this case 1 indicates a row field.  Position = if >1 field of the same orientation, where is this field positioned in that set?  This is all pretty well explained in the docs eg  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfield.position

Comment: The colon in this line is a statement delimiter, you can replace it with new line without changing code's meaning.

Comment: @BrakNicku - good job figuring out the actual question! Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649101/excel-vba-pound-and-colon-signs-meaning